# ISC has announced the end of life for ISC DHCP as of the end of 2022. Will ubuntu use kea DHCP instead of ISC DHCP as they suggest?

Tags: dhcp

for more information about DHCP EOL:
https://www.isc.org/blogs/isc-dhcp-eol/

Comment: kea is alerady in 22.04. It is up to you which dhcp server is used.